# What is the mode value for Personalized Access Token for github

Tags: git, github, devops

I knew the mode name for basic authentication that is user name and password.

```
[credential]
guiPrompt = true
gitHubAuthModes = basic
```

What is the mode name for Personalized Access token? I have created Personal Access token in GitHub Account. I would like to configure in git config file. However I don't know the mode name for Personal Access Token. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's `pat`. See the docs:

https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#credentialgithubauthmodes

```
git config --global credential.gitHubAuthModes pat
```

Comment: Perfect after adding pat in gitHubAuthModes. its working as we expected. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Whenever we used with browser authentication, the browser run in background from my application. Is this possible to forcibly run in foreground? Extremely sorry if my question was wrong

Comment: @LakshminarayananS I don't think there is a way.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation